# Lebesgue points of a.e. equal function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f=g$ pointwise a.e. in $\mathbb{R}$.
Then what can we say about the Lebesgue points of $f$ and $g$?

Clearly the set of Lebesgue points of $f$ (denoted by $L_f$)and that of $g$ (denoted by $L_g$)need not equal. Is there any relation between these two sets?

Can we expect something like $\mu(L_f) \cap \mu(L_g)=\mu(L_f)=\mu(L_g)$?

P.S.: Answers with a clean proof / a precise reference are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $f(x) = g(x)$ and $x$ is a Lebesgue point of either $f$ or $g$, it will also be a Lebesgue point of the other. This lets you say something about the symmetric difference $(L_f \setminus L_g) \cup (L_g \setminus L_f)$...

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Could you please elaborate a bit